# GSM modem Sierra Wireless EM7421 not working with Ubuntu 22.04 in Fujitsu Lifebook E5511

Tags: 22.04, modem, modem-manager

be warned:

There is a substantial issue with GSM modems in  Ubuntu 22.04 !

All former releases (18.x, 20.x, 21 up to 21.10) and all flavors (XFCE4) before 22.04 are not concerned.

IPv6 does not work at all over GSM.   
The issue causes interdependencies with WiFi control, too.   
Switching off WiFi breaks the GSM connect.   
Disabling modem-manager does not resolve it.

Modem is Sierra Wireless, Inc. EM7421  
you are well advised to upgrade the firmware but thats not related to the ubuntu bug.

Answer (score 0):

Bug report with launchpad  [Bug #1970086](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6020578.html) is issued.